# Aggregate quantity based on string and additional column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set that contains data that looks like this:

```
Month, Year, Quantity Sold, Product Name
11, 2017, 13, "Creatine Powder Supplement - 500g"
11, 2017, 10, "Gummies 1 bag"
11, 2017, 12, "Creatine Powder Supplement - 1000g"
11, 2017, 15, "Creatine Powder Supplement - 1500g"
11, 2017, 11, "Glucosamine - 500g"
11, 2017, 23, "Glucosamine - 1500g"
12, 2017, 17, "Creatine Powder Supplement - 1000g"
12, 2017, 24, "Glucosamine - 500g"
12, 2017, 13, "Glucosamine - 1500g"
1, 2018, 16, "Creatine Powder Supplement - 500g"
1, 2018, 13, "Creatine Powder Supplement - 1000g"
1, 2018, 10, "Gummies 1 bag"
1, 2018, 11, "Glucosamine - 500g"
1, 2018, 21, "Glucosamine - 1500g"
```

I want to calculate the total weight of products sold, separated by month and year, which would require extracting the weight of the product from the "Product Name" column, multiplying it by the "Quantity Sold" column, then providing the total for the related product.

Desired output (I've only calculated the total weight sold for the first row):

```
Matched data set:

Month, Year, Product Name, Total Weight Sold
11, 2017, Creatine Powder Supplement, 41000
11, 2017, Glucosamine, <total>
12, 2017, Creatine Powder Supplement, <total>
12, 2017, Glucosamine, <total>
1, 2018, Creatine Powder Supplement, <total>
1, 2018, Glucosamine, <total>
```

In addition to this, for any products that don't end in the pattern  `- <number>g`, I want to output these into a separate data set so they can be reviewed.

```
UNmatched data set:

Month, Year, Quantity Sold, Product Name
11, 2017, 10, "Gummies 1 bag"
1, 2018, 10, "Gummies 1 bag"
```

I'm thinking of using `str.extract` but I'm not totally sure how to do the math and then sum the resulting calculated total to other rows for the same product, into a new DataFrame or otherwise.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward solution I can think of is

```
product_data = df['Product Name'].str.extract('(?P<name>\w+) - (?P<weight>\d+)g')
invalid_rows = df[product_data['weight'].isnull()]
product_data.drop(labels=invalid_rows.index, inplace=True)
df.drop(labels=invalid_rows.index, inplace=True)
df['Product Name'] = product_data['name']
df['Total'] = product_data['weight'].astype(np.int32) * df['Quantity Sold']
print(df.groupby(['Month', 'Year', 'Product Name']).sum()['Total'].reset_index())
print()
print(invalid_rows)
```

Which outputs

```
  Month  Year Product Name  Total
0     1  2018     Creatine  21000
1     1  2018  Glucosamine  37000
2    11  2017     Creatine  41000
3    11  2017  Glucosamine  40000
4    12  2017     Creatine  17000
5    12  2017  Glucosamine  31500

   Month  Year Quantity Sold     Product Name
1     11  2017            10  "Gummies 1 bag"
11     1  2018            10  "Gummies 1 bag"
```

Comment: I think this is missing the second part, to output anything that doesn't match separately, but this answers the first. I'm going to update the example data set in the question to include non matching data.

Comment: So close! I did fail to mention that the Product Name often has multiple words. I have edited to reflect. The provided regex doesn't capture that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Python solution. It writes *error* lines to an output file and writes good lines to the terminal.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

d = defaultdict(int)

with open('f0.txt', 'r') as f, open('err.txt', 'w') as fout:
    fout.write(f.readline()) # print header to err.txt

    for row in f:
        row = row.rstrip()
        if re.search(r'- \d+g"', row):
            month, yr, qty, product = row.split(', ')
            product = product.replace('g', '').replace('"', '')
            name, grams = product.split(' - ')
            key = ','.join([month, yr, name])
            d[key] += int(qty) * int(grams)
        else:
            # handle this row (that doesn't have a Product and weight)
            fout.write(row + '\n')

print(','.join(['Month', 'Year', 'Product Name', 'Total Sold']))

for key, total in d.items():
    print(f'{key},{total}')
```

Prints to terminal:

```
Month,Year,Product Name,Total Sold
11,2017,Creatine,41000
11,2017,Glucosamine,40000
12,2017,Creatine,17000
12,2017,Glucosamine,31500
1,2018,Creatine,21000
1,2018,Glucosamine,37000
```

Prints to err.txt:

```
Month, Year, Quantity Sold, Product Name
11, 2017, 10, "Gummies 1 bag"
1, 2018, 10, "Gummies 1 bag"
```